# Android Studio including OsmAnd code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, build.gradle

I'm trying to include [OsmAnd](https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand) project from github in Android Studio. Unfortunately I get tons of problems. First of all I get this error

```
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
```

also I get some strange errors in my `AndroidMainifest.xml` file (I don't even imagine what's wrong with this file) for example at th begining of a file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.osmand"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="231"
    android:versionName="@string/app_version" >
```

I get that `installLocation, versionCode, versionName` attributes is not allowed here. I try to google about these errors but still can't find any answer. 
Here I add all Messages Build Gradle log

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :eclipse-compile:cardview:generateDebugSources, :eclipse-compile:cardview:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :eclipse-compile:cardview:compileDebugSources, :eclipse-compile:cardview:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :eclipse-compile:design:generateDebugSources, :eclipse-compile:design:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :eclipse-compile:design:compileDebugSources, :eclipse-compile:design:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateDebugSources, :eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileDebugSources, :eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugSources, :OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugAndroidTestSources, :OsmAnd:compileFreeLegacyArmv5DebugSources, :OsmAnd:compileFreeLegacyArmv5DebugAndroidTestSources, :plugins:Osmand-SRTMPlugin:generateDebugSources, :plugins:Osmand-SRTMPlugin:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :plugins:Osmand-SRTMPlugin:compileDebugSources, :plugins:Osmand-SRTMPlugin:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :plugins:Osmand-ParkingPlugin:generateDebugSources, :plugins:Osmand-ParkingPlugin:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :plugins:Osmand-ParkingPlugin:compileDebugSources, :plugins:Osmand-ParkingPlugin:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
WARNING [Project: :OsmAnd] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
Validating translations
:OsmAnd:cleanNoTranslate UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:clean
:OsmAnd-java:clean
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:clean
:eclipse-compile:cardview:clean
:eclipse-compile:design:clean
:plugins:Osmand-ParkingPlugin:clean UP-TO-DATE
:plugins:Osmand-SRTMPlugin:clean UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:checkDebugManifest
:eclipse-compile:cardview:prepareDebugDependencies
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileDebugAidl
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileDebugRenderscript
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateDebugBuildConfig
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:mergeDebugAssets
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateDebugResources
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageDebugResources
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processDebugManifest
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processDebugResources
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateDebugSources
:eclipse-compile:cardview:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileLint
:eclipse-compile:cardview:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileDebugJava
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processDebugJavaRes
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageDebugJar
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageDebugLocalJar
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:bundleDebug
:eclipse-compile:cardview:assembleDebug
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:eclipse-compile:cardview:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileDebugSources
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileDebugAndroidTestJava
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileDebugAndroidTestSources
:eclipse-compile:design:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:checkDebugManifest
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileLint
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:checkReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:prepareReleaseDependencies
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseAidl
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseRenderscript
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:mergeReleaseAssets
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseResources
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageReleaseResources
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processReleaseResources
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateReleaseSources
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseJava
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processReleaseJavaRes
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageReleaseJar
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageReleaseLocalJar
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:bundleRelease
:eclipse-compile:design:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:prepareOsmandEclipseCompileAppcompatUnspecifiedLibrary
:eclipse-compile:design:prepareDebugDependencies
:eclipse-compile:design:compileDebugAidl
:eclipse-compile:design:compileDebugRenderscript
:eclipse-compile:design:generateDebugBuildConfig
:eclipse-compile:design:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeDebugAssets
:eclipse-compile:design:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateDebugResources
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeDebugResources
:eclipse-compile:design:processDebugManifest
:eclipse-compile:design:processDebugResources
:eclipse-compile:design:generateDebugSources
:eclipse-compile:design:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:eclipse-compile:design:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:eclipse-compile:design:compileLint
:eclipse-compile:design:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:compileDebugJava
:eclipse-compile:design:processDebugJavaRes
:eclipse-compile:design:packageDebugJar
:eclipse-compile:design:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageDebugLocalJar
:eclipse-compile:design:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageDebugResources
:eclipse-compile:design:bundleDebug
:eclipse-compile:design:assembleDebug
:eclipse-compile:design:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:eclipse-compile:design:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:eclipse-compile:design:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:eclipse-compile:design:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:eclipse-compile:design:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:eclipse-compile:design:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:eclipse-compile:design:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:eclipse-compile:design:compileDebugSources
:eclipse-compile:design:compileDebugAndroidTestJava
:eclipse-compile:design:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:compileDebugAndroidTestSources
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:checkDebugManifest
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:prepareDebugDependencies
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileDebugAidl
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileDebugRenderscript
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateDebugBuildConfig
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:mergeDebugAssets
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateDebugResources
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageDebugResources
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processDebugManifest
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processDebugResources
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateDebugSources
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileDebugJava
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processDebugJavaRes
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageDebugJar
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageDebugLocalJar
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:bundleDebug
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:assembleDebug
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
Process list not empty
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileDebugSources
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileDebugAndroidTestJava
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:appcompat:compileDebugAndroidTestSources
:OsmAnd:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:checkFreeLegacyArmv5DebugManifest
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeLegacyX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoreX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreeQtcoredebugX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevLegacyX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoreX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFreedevQtcoredebugX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullLegacyX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoreX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv5DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv5ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugFatDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugFatReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugMipsDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugMipsReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:preFullQtcoredebugX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:compileJava
Note: C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd-java\src\net\osmand\util\GeoPointParserUtil.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:OsmAnd-java:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd-java:classes
:OsmAnd-java:androidJar
:eclipse-compile:cardview:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:checkReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:cardview:prepareReleaseDependencies
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseAidl
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseRenderscript
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:mergeReleaseAssets
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseResources
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageReleaseResources
Process list not empty
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processReleaseResources
:eclipse-compile:cardview:generateReleaseSources
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseJava
:eclipse-compile:cardview:processReleaseJavaRes
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageReleaseJar
:eclipse-compile:cardview:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageReleaseLocalJar
:eclipse-compile:cardview:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:cardview:bundleRelease
:eclipse-compile:design:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:checkReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:design:prepareReleaseDependencies
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseAidl
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseRenderscript
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeReleaseAssets
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseResources
:eclipse-compile:design:mergeReleaseResources
Process list not empty
:eclipse-compile:design:processReleaseManifest
:eclipse-compile:design:processReleaseResources
:eclipse-compile:design:generateReleaseSources
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseJava
:eclipse-compile:design:processReleaseJavaRes
:eclipse-compile:design:packageReleaseJar
:eclipse-compile:design:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageReleaseLocalJar
:eclipse-compile:design:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:eclipse-compile:design:packageReleaseResources
Process list not empty
:eclipse-compile:design:bundleRelease
:OsmAnd:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex100Library
:OsmAnd:prepareOsmandEclipseCompileAppcompatUnspecifiedLibrary
:OsmAnd:prepareOsmandEclipseCompileCardviewUnspecifiedLibrary
:OsmAnd:prepareOsmandEclipseCompileDesignUnspecifiedLibrary
:OsmAnd:prepareFreeLegacyArmv5DebugDependencies
:OsmAnd:compileFreeLegacyArmv5DebugAidl
:OsmAnd:compileFreeLegacyArmv5DebugRenderscript
:OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugBuildConfig
:OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:mergeFreeLegacyArmv5DebugAssets
:OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:OsmAnd:generateFreeLegacyArmv5DebugResources
:OsmAnd:mergeFreeLegacyArmv5DebugResources
AAPT err(37153474): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\warnings_speed_bump.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(1347914553): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\progress_grey.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(64492904): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\progress_green.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(1585662342): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\progress_orange.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(434005250): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-mdpi\progress_grey.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(1494866008): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\monitoring_rec_inactive.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(277725043): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\warnings_speed_camera.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(1494866008): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\monitoring_rec_small.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(1585662342): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\progress_blue.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(64492904): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\monitoring_rec_big.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(1347914553): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\pedestrian_small_white.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(1585662342): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_btn_wocheckbox_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(1597410500): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-mdpi\progress_blue.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(1494866008): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-large\warnings_speed_bump.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(592027313): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_btn_wocheckbox_pushed.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(98194391): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_btn_wocheckbox_notselected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(780771388): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\pedestrian_small.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(294798246): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-large\warnings_speed_camera.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(780771388): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-mdpi\progress_green.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(355798226): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-large\warnings_traffic_calming.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(294798246): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-mdpi\progress_orange.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(355798226): C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_overflow_menu_light.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
Process list not empty
:OsmAnd:processFreeLegacyArmv5DebugManifest
:OsmAnd:processFreeLegacyArmv5DebugResources
warning: string 'poi_bedding' has no default translation.
warning: string 'poi_building_poi' has no default translation.
warning: string 'poi_car_wash_self_service' has no default translation.
warning: string 'poi_general_tourist_attraction_yes' has no default translation.
warning: string 'poi_historic_monastery' has no default translation.
warning: string 'poi_mill_pond' has no default translation.
warning: string 'poi_team_handball' has no default translation.
warning: string 'poi_tourism_attraction' has no default translation.
C:\Users\Deividas\Documents\Android Studio Projects\OSM222\Osmand\OsmAnd\build\intermediates\manifests\full\freelegacyarmv5\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(7, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'versionName' with value '@string/app_version').
Error:(81, 25) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(141, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(354, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(464, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(478, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/osm_live').
Error:Execution failed for task ':OsmAnd:processFreeLegacyArmv5DebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Deividas\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 48.548 secs
Information:7 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console

  [1]: https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand
```

What is strange that I don't change anything in code that can cause these problems. Any ideas what can be wrong? And most importantly have ever include this project successfully?

Comment: As per the errors, strings are missing. Add them to resolve the issue

Comment: I have my string.xml file and there are all strings but my IDE say that string are missing.

Comment: They are missing in library string file probably. Try to include there

Comment: Well but why I get attribute errors in my AndroidMainifest file?

Comment: Because `app_name` string is missing from the resource string file. I think your app supports multi-lingual. Make sure you have declared in all string files

Comment: Thank You! Now is it possible to solve this `Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.` problem?

Comment: Ignore it as long as it is not causing any trouble.